# CIAdditionCompositing seg faults

Tags: swift, core-graphics, cifilter

I'm trying to create a tilt shift filter as per [Apple's instructions](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_filer_recipes/ci_filter_recipes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185-CH4-SW17) but as soon as I try and get the `outputImage` from the CIAdditionCompositing filter I get a seg fault.  This is the code I'm using as an extension on UIImage.  What is it that I'm doing wrong?

```swift
public func tiltShift() -> UIImage? {
    guard let backingCi = ciImage ?? CIImage(image: self) else {
        return nil
    }

    let blurred = backingCi.applyingGaussianBlur(sigma: 10)

    var gradientParameters = [
        "inputPoint0": CIVector(x: 0, y: 0.75 * size.height),
        "inputColor0": CIColor(red: 0, green: 1, blue: 0, alpha: 1),
        "inputPoint1": CIVector(x: 0, y: 0.5 * 10),
        "inputColor1": CIColor(red: 0, green: 1, blue: 0, alpha: 0)
    ];

    guard let inputGradient = CIFilter(name: "CILinearGradient", parameters: gradientParameters),
        let inputImage = inputGradient.outputImage else {
            return nil
    }

    gradientParameters["inputPoint0"] = CIVector(x: 0, y: 0.25 * size.height)

    guard let backgroundGradient = CIFilter(name: "CILinearGradient", parameters: gradientParameters),
        let backgroundImage = backgroundGradient.outputImage else {
            return nil
    }

    let maskParameters = [
        "inputImage": inputImage,
        "inputBackgroundImage": backgroundImage
    ]

    guard let mask = CIFilter(name: "CIAdditionCompositing", parameters: maskParameters),
        let maskedImage = mask.outputImage else {  // <=- This line aborts
            return nil
    }

    let combinedParameters = [
        "inputImage": blurred,
        "inputBackgroundImage": self,
        "inputMaskImage": maskedImage
    ]

    guard let blend = CIFilter(name: "CIBlendWithMask", parameters: combinedParameters) else {
        return nil
    }

    let context = CIContext(options: nil)

    guard let blendImg = blend.outputImage,
        let cgimg = context.createCGImage(blendImg, from: blendImg.extent) else { return nil }

    return UIImage(cgImage: cgimg)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `UIImage` instead of `CIImage` in `combinedParameters` and `UIImage` doesn't have `extent` method so you are getting the crash. You need to use the `CIImage` created on top from the current image as below,

```
let combinedParameters = [
    "inputImage": blurred,
    "inputBackgroundImage": backingCi,
    "inputMaskImage": maskedImage
]
```

Comment: Doesn't crash now, but I'm definitely not getting a proper tilt shift :(

Comment: I'm just trying to implement what is shown in the link to Apple's doc.  Filters like this are all new to me

Comment: It's a Playground issue.  If I move the code to an actual iOS app, for example, it works exactly as expected.  Thanks for pointing out the issue!